# Print arrays one after the other

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, xml-parsing

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to print a group - say three - arrays one after the other.

```
Node A
    Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
Node B
    Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
    Element 4
Node C
    Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
```

Each node has different attributes, so my code is set up to go to each node with that specific attribute and populate an array. But when I go to print, each statement just overlaps the next. I can't figure out how to print the arrays without just shifting the starting cell.

For example,

```
Range("A" & j + 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArray1)
Range("B" & j + 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArray2)
```

I want to start printing at A3 and increment by `j`, but all this does is push the printing to A5 (if j = 2). I know that I have to increment, I just don't know how.

Edit: Here's my main chunk of code:

```
For i = 0 To (count - 1)
ReDim Preserve NodeIDArray(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeVersionArray(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeIDArray_v13(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeIDArray_v14(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeID_Version13(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeID_Version14(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve NodeIDNameArray(0 To count)
ReDim Preserve CellIDArray(0 To count)

If NodeVersionArray(i) = "13" Then
    NodeID_Version13 = NodeIDArray(i)
    NodeIDArray_v13(i) = NodeID_Version13
    Node_Version13 = NodeVersionArray(i)
    NodeID_Version13(i) = Node_Version13


    Set version13_loc = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/home/Equipment[@id='" & NodeID_Version13 & "' and @version='" & Node_Version13 & "']/room/cell")
    Set version_13_count = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/home/Equipment[@version='13']")
    For j = 0 To (version13_loc.Length - 1)
        ReDim Preserve CellIDArray(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve NodeIDNameArray(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve CellIDNameArray13(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve NodeIDNameArray13(0 To j)

        CellID = version13_loc(j).getAttribute("id")
        NodeIDName = version13_loc(j).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
        CellIDArray(j) = CellID
        NodeIDNameArray(j) = NodeIDName

        v13Count = version_13_count.Length

        Range("A" & j + 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NodeIDNameArray)
        Range("B" & j + 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CellIDArray)
     Next
     Call PrintDatav13(NodeIDNameArray, CellIDArray, j, v13Count)
ElseIf NodeVersionArray(i) = "14" Then
    NodeID_Version14 = NodeIDArray(i)
    NodeIDArray_v14(i) = NodeID_Version14
    Node_Version14 = NodeVersionArray(i)
    NodeID_Version14(i) = Node_Version14

    Set version14_loc = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/home/Equipment[@id='" & NodeID_Version14 & "' and @version='" & Node_Version14 & "']/room/cell/location")
    For k = 0 To (version14_loc.Length - 1)
        ReDim Preserve CellIDArray(0 To k)
        ReDim Preserve NodeIDNameArray(0 To k)
        ReDim Preserve CellIDNameArray14(0 To k)
        ReDim Preserve NodeIDNameArray14(0 To k)
        ReDim Preserve PurposeNameArray(0 To k)

        PurposeName = version14_loc(k).Text
        CellID = version14_loc(k).ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
        NodeIDName = version14_loc(k).ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")

        If PurposeName = "Red" Or PurposeName = "Orange" Or PurposeName = "Blue" Then

            CellIDArray(h) = CellID
            NodeIDNameArray(h) = NodeIDName
            PurposeNameArray(h) = PurposeName

            h = h + 1
        End If
    Next
    Call PrintDatav14(CellIDArray, NodeIDNameArray, PurposeNameArray, h)
Else
    MsgBox ("Wrong Version")
End If


Next

Sub PrintDatav14(NodeIDNameArray, CellIDArray, PurposeNameArray, h)
Range("A3").Resize(h, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NodeIDNameArray)
Range("B3").Resize(h, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CellIDArray)
Range("C3").Resize(h, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PurposeNameArray)
End Sub
```

So for version 13 (after the first IF) I try to print after the statement. For version 14, I create a sub that prints (just for experimental purposes). They however overlap.

Comment: Would help to show more of your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry, I forgot to add it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my error.. and it's due to confusion of variable names.

The lesson here is to not have awful and similar variable names.